# How to uniquely identify a cronjob run from within the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I currently have a kubernetes CronJob with a `concurrencyPolicy: Forbid`.
I would like to be able to uniquely identify this pod externally (k8 cluster) and internally from the pod, with an ID that will be unique forever.
I was thinking of using the `creationTimestamp` and the name of the pod but unfortunately it is [not that easy to pass the `creationTimestamp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72873334/how-to-pass-creation-timestamp-to-kubernetes-cronjob/72874894#72874894). Any other ideas?

Comment: You can simply attach a label to the `CronJob` that you can ensure is unique.

Comment: seems like you're giving XY problem question. you should really ask a question around what your original problem is and not around the solution you think will solve it. it will help give you better answers. anyways, i'll answer this one directly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the pod name like you had figured out from your other question:

```
- name: POD_NAME
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: metadata.name
```

The pod name should be very unique (if you want completely unique, you'll need to grab its UID, but i'm not sure what you're trying to solve).

The pod name will be generated using the following format:

```
{{CRONJOB_NAME}}-{{UNIX_TIMESTAMP_IN_MINUTES}}-{{5_CHAR_RANDOM_ALPHANUM}}
```